# How to login to google account with playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I have following source code and run it in headful mode.
I can input email address.
But, after that, there is message that saying "Couldn't sign you in.For your protection, you can't sign in from this device. Try again later, or sign in from another device.".

Do I need to set additional header or something else?

Here is my source code.

```
const playwright = require('playwright');
const cookiePath = '/home/ubuntu/.config/chromium/Default';
browser['chromium'] = await playwright['chromium'].launchPersistentContext(cookiePath,{
  headless: false,
  args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
      ],
});
const page = await browser['chromium'].newPage();
const login_url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ja&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"; 
await page.goto(login_url);
await page.fill('#identifierId',userinfo['id']);
await page.click("#identifierNext");
await page.fill('[name=password]',userinfo['password']);
await page.click("#passwordNext");
```

Comment: it's for your protection

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:
add `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` to your `args`.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ["--disable-dev-shm-usage"],
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext({});
    const page = await context.newPage();
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
    });
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(
        "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
    );
    await navigationPromise;
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]');
    await page.type('input[type="email"]', "youremail");
    await page.click("#identifierNext");
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]', { visible: true });
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', "yourpassword");
    await page.waitForSelector("#passwordNext", { visible: true });
    await page.click("#passwordNext");
    await navigationPromise;
    //you are in
```

I think you can search for login to google with Puppeteer also.

Comment: How were you able to deduce the selectors #passwordNext and #identifierNext? Seems like everything is munged and the selectors aren't visible right now. It still works though.

Comment: I'm following the Authentication instructions, looks like it is logging in but then loses the browser or something before the tests get run https://playwright.dev/docs/auth

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages']
})
```

Comment: Still getting the same even after adding this argument