# Playwright - How to test a website that requires google login

Tags: testing, web, playwright

We are currently developing a new website, that right now requires to login with work google account in order to access anything.
I've tried setting extrahttpHeaders in playwright.config.ts - but it changes nothing.
How should I approach it?
The website is using cloudflare

Comment: Did you try google it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139098/how-to-login-to-google-account-with-playwright can help you

Comment: Hello helpful person! Naturally I've tried to google it like everyone should, but the thread you shared does not answer my question. If you know how to do it without hardcoding the password to a account, I would be happy to hear your solution. :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

There should be way through Oauth2. I did not it by myself but basically you send HTTP request to google API and they send you access token back. [Watch this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)